# Validate RegExp in external .js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex

Here's a perplexing problem.

I have a site that uses AJAX in which the primary home page loads a home.js file with core scripts that are required by all pages on the site.  One of these core scripts is the following RegExp:

```
var datePattern = new RegExp("^([0][1-9]|[1][0-2])\/([0][1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|[3][0-1])\/([12][0-9][0-9][0-9])$");
```

When the user goes to a page (via AJAX), the appropriate form validation script.js file is loaded first which contains the following to validate dates (where val is the value of the date element and correctly displays the anticipated date value):

```
var val=elem[i].value;
if (!datePattern.test(val)) {
    elem[i].style.background="#FF0000";
    errno++;
}
```

I have passed both the script and the HTML through a validator and everything appears to be ok.

Everything works fine in FF.  However in IE. I get the message that the datePattern is undefined.  What is it about the datePattern declaration in the home.js file that I need to change to ensure it is available globally to other js files?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you use a Javascript library which has date validation already?

Comment: The file is likely not loaded when you are trying to access the function. IE does like a setTimeout or a defer

Comment: No, I am not using a JS Library, though it's worth looking into.  As for the file being loaded, yes, it is actually loaded.  The script from the home.js file works flawlessly and the script containing the $datePattern.test function works fine...it just registers the datePattern as Undefined.  (There are other validation steps that occur before and after that work fine if I step over the datePattern.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original regex expression and syntax worked fine.  The problem was with another jquery syntax that was failing and not reporting an error, which caused the subsequent expressions to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Scripts on a page are executed one after another.  Logically, all that needs to happen is the needle-defining-line is executed before whatever needs it.  On a static page it's as simple as putting it before the other JS in the markup.  In AJAX it needs to be loaded and somehow executed before the other one, which may prove more difficult.

The other common problem is scope.  Since you're using `var`, the variable will be local to its own scope.  Make sure that line isn't in a function call.  A good way to narrow down the problem is to remove the `var` keyword.  If the problem is fixed; blame scope.  If it persists; blame execution order.

I hope that helps with the debugging.

Comment: I've tried removing the var component with no luck.  It is declared at the opening of the home.js file and the second js file is loaded after that and appears to be properly loaded when I view it in IE's script developer tools.  So I don't think it's a problem with the script loading.  I have a feeling that it's a scope issue, but I can't figure out why a global variable in the first js file would not be available to subsequently loaded js files.  Again, this works fine in FF, but not IE.  Any other scope related ideas to try?

Comment: Figured it out.  I apparently have an unreported error somewhere in my home.js file that IE doesn't like so it fails to load the var datePattern correctly later...although all other script elements run fine.  Thanks for your help all!

Comment: @Max, you could post that as an answer, and accept it.  The error might be helpful to anyone looking at this later on.